# How to get the results of a count distinct combined with a group by in wide format?

Tags: sql, presto

Let us assume I have a table `t1` that looks like this:

```
week | id | country
-----+----+--------
1    | 1  | D      
1    | 2  | E      
1    | 3  | E      
2    | 1  | D      
2    | 4  | D
```

My goal is to get a table `t2` that reports for each country the number of distinct ids:

```
week | distinct_ids_D | distinct_ids_E
-----+----------------+---------------
1    | 1              | 2
2    | 2              | 0
```

My idea was to do a normal `group_by`:

```
SELECT week, country, COUNT(DISTINCT id) count FROM t1 GROUP BY week, country
```

But this gives me `t2` in long format:

```
week | country | count
-----+---------+--------
1    | D       | 1      
1    | E       | 2      
2    | D       | 2      
2    | E       | 0
```

How to get it in wide format? The solution should be in Presto.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `country` in `GROUP BY` clause since you want count `e` country

```
SELECT week, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) as distinct_ids_D,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN country = 'E' then country END) as distinct_ids_E
FROM t1 
GROUP BY week;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second column expression read `SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'D'...`?

Comment: @sticky bit: yes. However, the main problem is that `SUM(...)` counts all the `article_ids`; it is not a count distinct.

Comment: @Joe. . . So, you want count with `distinct` ?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the title and text of my post.

Comment: @Yogesh: I tested your new solution, but it does not work. For each week it says the number of distinct ids is 1. Besides that, as pointed out by sticky bit, the second column should be build in the same way as the third one.